# Sending data to API and retrieving them in to a grid

Tags: mysql, extjs, yii2

In my project I am using extjs in front-end. yii2 in backend. I created a form to retrieve selected data from database.

[image]

As you can see I have two date fields and a dropdown list. And I have a group of checkboxes. This is a screenshot of my database table.

[image]

I should select the data I want using checkboxes and get them from database between 'from' to 'to' dates. When I click RUN button those selected data should be loaded to the grid in the below. When I click download button, those selected data should be downloaded to a csv file. But when I click RUN button it sends same API call twice. And one API gets data correctly and other one sends and error saying 'Undefined index: from'. This is the code in my view.

```
           recordData: {
              date: null,
              from: null,
              to: null,
              rb1: null,
              rb1: null,
              rb2: null,
              rb3: null,
              rb4: null,
              time: null,
              rb5: null,
              rb6: null,
              rb7: null,
              weight: 0,
              status: 1
        }
  },

  initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.title = 'Reports',
              me.store = Ext.create('store.Reports');

        Ext.apply(me, {
              items: [{
                    xtype: 'form',
                    border: false,
                    padding: 10,
                    bodyStyle: { "background-color": "#e4e4e4" },
                    width: '100%',

                    store: me.store,
                    defaults: {
                          selectOnFocus: true,
                          labelWidth: 125
                    },

                    items: [{
                          xtype: 'datefield',
                          fieldLabel: 'From',
                          padding: '10 0 0 40',
                          name: 'from',
                          format: 'Y-m-d',
                          labelWidth: 150,
                          value: me.recordData.from,
                          displayField: 'from',
                          typeAhead: true,
                          queryMode: 'local',
                          emptyText: 'Select...'
                    }, {
                          xtype: 'datefield',
                          fieldLabel: 'To',
                          padding: '20 0 0 40',
                          name: 'to',
                          format: 'Y-m-d',
                          labelWidth: 150,
                          value: me.recordData.to,
                          displayField: 'to',
                          typeAhead: true,
                          queryMode: 'local',
                          emptyText: 'Select...'
                    }, {
                          xtype: 'combobox',
                          fieldLabel: 'Report Type',
                          padding: '20 0 0 40',
                          name: 'type',
                          labelWidth: 150,
                          store: [
                                ['Order Report', 'Order Report']

                          ],
                          value: me.recordData.type,
                          displayField: 'type',
                          typeAhead: true,
                          queryMode: 'local',
                          emptyText: 'Select...'
                    }, {
                          width: '100%',
                          bodyStyle: { "background-color": "#e4e4e4" },
                          padding: '20 0 0 40',
                          bodyPadding: 10,
                          renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                          items: [{
                                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                                fieldLabel: 'Customize Report',
                                width: 700,
                                labelWidth: 150,
                                columns: 3,
                                vertical: false,
                                items: [
                                      { boxLabel: 'Order ID', name: 'rb1', inputValue: '1', itemId: 'check1' },
                                      { boxLabel: 'Connection Number', name: 'rb2', inputValue: '2', itemId: 'check2' },
                                      { boxLabel: 'Status', name: 'rb3', inputValue: '3', itemId: 'check3' },
                                      { boxLabel: 'Action', name: 'rb4', inputValue: '4', itemId: 'check4' },
                                      { boxLabel: 'LOB', name: 'rb5', inputValue: '5', itemId: 'check5' },
                                      { boxLabel: 'Channel', name: 'rb6', inputValue: '6', itemId: 'check6' },
                                      { boxLabel: 'Company Name', name: 'rb7', inputValue: '7', itemId: 'check7' }
                                ]
                          }]
                    }, {
                          buttons: [{
                                xtype: 'button',
                                text: 'RUN',
                                itemId: 'btnRun',
                                handler: function (button, event) {
                                      //console.log("Working!", form);
                                      var form = button.up('form');
                                      //targetGridpanel = button.up();
                                      //console.log("Working!", targetGridpanel);
                                      //console.log("Working!", form);
                                      if (form.isDirty()) {
                                            var _vals = form.getValues();

                                            if (!form.isValid()) {
                                                  console.log("Not Working!");
                                                  Ext.Msg.show({
                                                        icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                                                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                                                        title: me.action + ' Report',
                                                        msg: 'Fill mandatory fields'
                                                  });
                                            } else {
                                                  //console.log(_vals);
                                                  me.store.saveRecord(_vals, function () {
                                                  });
                                                  //me.store.load();
                                                  if (me.down('#check1').isDirty()) {
                                                        me.down('#rb1').show(true);
                                                  }
                                                  if (me.down('#check2').isDirty()) {
                                                        me.down('#rb2').show(true);
                                                  }
                                                  if (me.down('#check3').isDirty()) {
                                                        me.down('#rb3').show(true);
                                                  }
                                                  if (me.down('#check4').isDirty()) {
                                                        me.down('#rb4').show(true);
                                                  }
                                                  if (me.down('#check5').isDirty()) {
                                                        me.down('#rb5').show(true);
                                                        me.down('#time').show(true);
                                                  }
                                                  if (me.down('#check6').isDirty()) {
                                                        me.down('#rb6').show(true);
                                                  }
                                                  if (me.down('#check7').isDirty()) {
                                                        me.down('#rb7').show(true);
                                                  }
                                            }
                                      } else {
                                            console.log("Close!");
                                      }
                                }
                          }]
                    }, {
                          xtype: 'gridpanel',
                          store: me.store,
                          flex: 1,
                          margin: '20 0 0 0',
                          //minHeight: 300,
                          height: 240,
                          viewConfig: {
                                stripeRows: true
                          },

                          bbar: {
                                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                                store: me.store,
                                displayInfo: true,
                                plugins: Ext.create('Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager')
                          },

                          columns: [{
                                dataIndex: 'date',
                                //itemId:'date',
                                text: 'DATE',
                                flex: 1,
                                menuDisabled: false,
                          }, {
                                dataIndex: 'rb1',
                                itemId: 'rb1',
                                text: 'ORDER ID',
                                flex: 1,
                                menuDisabled: false,
                                hidden: true,
                          }, {
                                dataIndex: 'rb2',
                                itemId: 'rb2',
                                text: 'CONNECTION NUMBER',
                                menuDisabled: false,
                                hidden: true,
                                flex: 2
                          }, {
                                dataIndex: 'rb3',
                                itemId: 'rb3',
                                text: 'STATUS',
                                menuDisabled: false,
                                hidden: true,
                                flex: 1
                          }, {
                                dataIndex: 'rb5',
                                itemId: 'rb5',
                                text: 'LOB',
                                menuDisabled: false,
                                hidden: true,
                                flex: 1
                          }, {
                                dataIndex: 'rb4',
                                itemId: 'rb4',
                                text: 'ACTION',
                                menuDisabled: false,
                                hidden: true,
                                flex: 1
                          }, {
                                dataIndex: 'time',
                                itemId: 'time',
                                text: 'ACTION TIME',
                                menuDisabled: false,
                                hidden: true,
                                flex: 1
                          }, {
                                dataIndex: 'rb6',
                                itemId: 'rb6',
                                text: 'CHANNEL',
                                menuDisabled: false,
                                hidden: true,
                                flex: 1
                          }, {
                                dataIndex: 'rb7',
                                itemId: 'rb7',
                                text: 'COMPANY NAME',
                                menuDisabled: false,
                                hidden: true,
                                flex: 1.5
                          }]
                    }
                    , {
                          buttons: [{
                                xtype: 'button',
                                text: 'DOWNLOAD',
                                itemId: 'download',
                                //actionMethods: {'read': 'POST'},
                                handler: function (button, event) {
                                      var self = button.up();
                                      var form = self.up('form');
                                      var vals = form.getValues();
                                      //console.log('Download', vals);
                                      if (vals.from && vals.to && vals.type && (vals.rb1 || vals.rb2 || vals.rb3 || vals.rb4 || vals.rb5 || vals.rb6 || vals.rb7)) {
                                            if (button) {
                                                  Ext.Msg.show({
                                                        icon: Ext.MessageBox.QUESTION,
                                                        buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
                                                        title: 'Download Report',
                                                        msg: 'Do you want to download the <strong>selected</strong> report file?',

                                                        fn: function (buttonId, text, opt) {

                                                              if ('yes' == buttonId) {
                                                                    //console.log(buttonId);
                                                                    var dummyFormId = 'py-form-' + (new Date()).getTime();
                                                                    //console.log(dummyFormId);
                                                                    var frm = document.createElement('form');
                                                                    frm.id = dummyFormId;
                                                                    frm.name = dummyFormId;
                                                                    //console.log(frm);
                                                                    frm.className = 'x-hidden';
                                                                    document.body.appendChild(frm);

                                                                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                                                                          url: utils.createUrl('api', 'report-download'),
                                                                          form: Ext.fly(dummyFormId),
                                                                          isUpload: true,

                                                                          params: {
                                                                                from: vals.from,
                                                                                to: vals.to,
                                                                                type: vals.type,
                                                                                rb1: vals.rb1,
                                                                                rb2: vals.rb2,
                                                                                rb3: vals.rb3,
                                                                                rb4: vals.rb4,
                                                                                rb5: vals.rb5,
                                                                                rb6: vals.rb6,
                                                                                rb7: vals.rb7
                                                                          },

                                                                          callback: function (opts, success, res) {
                                                                                console.log('Hello');
                                                                                //Ext.getBody().unmask();
                                                                                //console.log(params);
                                                                                try {
                                                                                      if (success) {
                                                                                            var response = Ext.decode(res.responseText);
                                                                                            if (!response.success) {
                                                                                                  throw response.data;
                                                                                            }
                                                                                      } else {
                                                                                            throw response.data;
                                                                                      }
                                                                                } catch (ex) {
                                                                                      Ext.Msg.show({
                                                                                            icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                                                                                            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                                                                                            title: 'Download Report',
                                                                                            msg: 'No Data Found'
                                                                                      });
                                                                                }
                                                                          },

                                                                          // fn: function () {
                                                                          //       console.log(arguments);
                                                                          // }
                                                                    });
                                                              }
                                                        }
                                                  });
                                            }
                                      } else {
                                            Ext.Msg.show({
                                                  icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                                                  buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                                                  title: 'Download Report',
                                                  msg: 'Please fill the form first'
                                            });
                                      }
                                }
                          }
                    ]

                    }
              ]
              }],

        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
```

I send these data to a store file. This is store file code.

```
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'model.Report',

storeId: 'reportStore',
autoLoad: false,
pageSize: Configs.grid.pageSize,

saveRecord: function(data,fnCallBack) {
    var me = this;
    //var data = this.data;
    //autoLoad: true,
    //console.log(data);
    Ext.getBody().mask('Please wait...');
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: utils.createUrl('api', 'report-read'),
        params: data,

        callback: function(opts, success, res) {
            Ext.getBody().unmask();

            try {
                if(success) {
                    var response = App.decodeHttpResp(res.responseText);

                    if(response.success) {
                        Ext.Msg.show({
                            icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO,
                            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                            title: 'Reports',
                            msg: 'Report saved successfully'
                        });
                    } else {
                        throw response.error;
                    }
                    me.load();
                } else {
                    throw 'Unknown Reason';
                }
            } catch (ex) {
                Ext.Msg.show({
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                    title: 'Report',
                    msg: 'Failed to save data<br />' +
                         'Reason: ' + ex
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is my front-end model.

```
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields: [
    { name: 'from', type: 'auto' },
    { name: 'to', type: 'auto' },
    { name: 'rb1', type: 'auto' },
    { name: 'rb2', type: 'auto' },
    { name: 'rb3', type: 'auto' },
    { name: 'rb4', type: 'auto' },
    { name: 'rb5', type: 'auto' },
    { name: 'time', type: 'auto' },
    { name: 'rb6', type: 'auto' },
    { name: 'rb7', type: 'auto' }
],


proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    noCache: false,

    actionMethods: {'read': 'POST'},

    api: {
        read: utils.createUrl('api', 'report-read'),
        //create: utils.createUrl('api', 'user-update'),
        // update: utils.createUrl('api', 'user-update'),
        // destroy: utils.createUrl('api', 'user-delete')
    },

    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    },

    listeners: {
        exception: function(proxy, response, operation) {
            App.showHttpError('Reports', response);
            //console.log(this.fields);
        }
    }
}
```

Using these files I send data to controller. That's where my API is defined.

This is my controller function.

```
public function actionReportRead(){

    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $time = 0;
    $_vals = (new Order())->readReports(
        @$post['start'],
        @$post['limit'],
        $post['from'],
        $post['to'],
        @$post['rb1'],
        @$post['rb2'],
        @$post['rb3'],
        @$post['rb5'],
        @$post['rb4'],
        @$time,
        @$post['rb6'],
        @$post['rb7']
    );
    $this->setOutputData($_vals);
    $this->setOutputStatus(true);
}
```

This is the model for that.

```
    public function readReports($start, $limit,$from,$to, $rb1, $rb2, $rb3, $rb5, $rb4, $time, $rb6, $rb7 )
{

    if (!$start) { $start = 0; };
    if (!$limit) { $limit = Config::PAGE_SIZE; };

    //$q = (new ActiveQuery(self::className()));
    $q = self::find();
    //$q->where(['between', 'submitted_time', $from, $to ]);
    $q->alias('T')->andWhere(['BETWEEN', 'T.submitted_time', $from, $to ]);

    $q->limit($limit);
    $q->offset($start);
    $q->orderBy(['T.order_id' => SORT_ASC]);

    $data = [];
    $action = null;
    foreach ($q->all() as $_o) {
        if($_o->status == 2){
            $action = 'Data Entry Verified';
            $time = $_o->timeDataEntry;
        }else if($_o->status == 3){
            $action = 'QC Accepted';
            $time = $_o->timeQcPass;
        }else if($_o->status == 4){
            $action = 'Accepted';
            $time = $_o->timeVerify;
        }else if($_o->status == 1){
            $action = 'Verification Pending';
            $time = $_o->timeQcReject;
        }else if($_o->status == 0){
            $action = 'Rejected';
            $time = $_o->timeQcReject;
        }

        $userlist='SELECT name FROM Company WHERE id = '.$_o->company_id;
        $rsuserlist = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($userlist)->query();
        $row = $rsuserlist->read();

        $data[] = (object) array(
            'date'        =>$_o->submitted_time,
            'rb1'        =>$_o->order_id,
            'rb2'        =>$_o->conn,
            'rb3'        =>$_o->status,
            'rb5'        =>$_o->conn_type,
            'rb4'        =>$action,
            'time'        =>$time,
            'rb6'        =>$_o->channel,
            'rb7'        =>$row['name']
        );

    }

    $json=Json::encode($data);
    $this->logger->actLog($json);
    return $data;

}
```

As I have found backend is fine. But I am not pretty sure. I new to extjs. So, I tried many ways but nothing worked. Data is not being loaded to grid and API sends me the error, I mentioned before. Please help me to solve this problem. What should I do more.

Comment: and whats the error ?

Comment: I see an error saying Undefined index 'from' in API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and I am answering my own question.

Here, one API gets all the data correctly. Other one doesn't get 'from' and 'to' values. So I used following code.

```
me.store.getProxy().extraParams = {
    from: vals.from,
    to: vals.to
};
```

Using this I could send all the parameters to other API and eliminate that issue. Now data is fetched to the grid without a problem.